# Calculations multiple arrays in foreach loop?

Tags: php, foreach

I have a database and perform a SQL-request against it to retrieve data. I use a LIMIT statement in my SQL-request to only retrieve eight rows of the SELECT-ed db-data at a time and the DESC-command to sort the data returned in descending order. More data can then be added in the same fashion via a dedicated load-button that performs an ajax-request.

The arrays in my `foreach ($result as $data)` have the following structure/key-value-pairs.

- `print_r($data)` shows the following:

```
Array (
    [*keyname0*] => group-id
    [*keyname1*] => name of 1st-item
    [*keyname2*] => state of 1st-item
    [*keyname3*] => 93.42
    [*keyname4*] => unit of 1st-item
)

Array (
    [*keyname0*] => group-id
    [*keyname1*] => name of 2nd-item
    [*keyname2*] => state of 2nd-item
    [*keyname3*] => 93.12
    [*keyname4*] => unit of 2nd-item
)

Array (
    [*keyname0*] => group-id 
    [*keyname1*] => name of 3rd-item
    [*keyname2*] => state of 3rd-item
    [*keyname3*] => 89.92
    [*keyname4*] => unit of 3rd-item
)

Array (
    [*keyname0*] => group-id 
    [*keyname1*] => name of 4th-item
    [*keyname2*] => state of 4th-item
    [*keyname3*] => 89.70
    [*keyname4*] => unit of 4th-item
)
...
```

**My aim** is to calculate over the multiple items/arrays that get (dynamically) created by the foreach-loop

- The calculation should follow this logic: deduct the value of *keyname3* of the 2nd item/array (i. e. 93.12) from the value of *keyname3* (i. e. 93.42) of the 1st item/array and so forth (i. e. 2nd from 1st, 3rd from 2nd, 4th from 3rd, 5th from 4th and so forth)

The results for the first arrays displayed above should be accordingly:

- 93.42 - 93.12 = -0.30
- 93.12 - 89.92 = -3.20
- 89.92 - 89.70 = -0.22
- ...

**My attempts**

- Creating a “shift” in the variable $data with next() or arrray_slice(): $data['keyname3']-array_slice($data['keyname3'], 3, 1). This didnt work.
- After that, my theory was to use two variables that derive from different SQL-requests. I used OFFSET in one of my SQL-requests in order to skip the first array. I then created a nested foreach-loop. This returned some valid results (among them my wanted values), but due to the nested foreach, for every iteration of the superordinated foreach it iterated through all values of the subordinate foreach (if that makes sense). By using a break, I was able to at least get the first value right. This was the nearest I could get to what I actually want. This is what the code looked like at this point (divs are wrapped in a foreach like so "foreach($result as $data) :" and ending with "endforeach;"):

  ```
   <div class="classa">
       <div><img class="classb" src="../../../img/test.png" alt="Image"></div>
       <div class="classc"><p><?php echo number_format((round($data['keyname3'],2)),2,'.',' ') . " " . $data['keyname6']; ?></p></div>
       <div class="classd"><p><?php echo $data['keyname2'] ?></p></div>
   </div>
   <div class="classe">
       <p>
           <?php 
               foreach($resultdiff as $key => $value) {
                   echo (round($value['keyname3']-$data['keyname3'],2));
                   if (++$count == 1) break;
               }
           ?>
       </p>
   </div>
  ```

**My output**

This code in combination with the SQL-request displays eight elements with a picture, the name, the value of the according item and the calculated value in the browser. The 1st element contains the correct calculation for that item and shows the value of **-3.50**. So far so good. The following items then display a list of values, like the following.

- 2nd: 0, **-3.2**, -3.42, -4.99, -5.21, -5.22, -5.43, -5.55
- 3rd: 3.2, 0, **-0.22**, -1.79, -2.01, -2.02, -2.23, -2.35
- ...

The bold values are the correct values for that specific element. When I hit the load-button it really gets queer, because all values are stacked upon the previous. So the nested foreach loop with the separate SQL-request doesnt seem to really work for me! **Is there a way to avoid a separate SQL-request with another variable and just use the already existing variable `$data` for this task?**

I am an absolute beginner and not at all sure, whether this is alltogether a totally wrong approach or a possible right track. I would really appreciate if someone could break this issue down for me or nudge me in the right direction. Every help is more than welcome, since this is a must-have for my project.

BTW: I haven't yet looked into alternative options, like using JavaScript. If that might be the more suitable approach to get the wanted result, this would also be fine with me. I am still clinging on to `PHP` for this issue.

Comment: If you know your array pattern means that 2 multidimension you can use foreach in foreach, if other you can use arraywalk, or recursive function. Please search array walk and recursuve function

Comment: Can you please provide us with example data and example output? Only dumping one element will not cut it.

Comment: Your `$result` is a "standard" array, with consecutive numeric keys starting at 0, yes? Then you don't need any `next` or `array_slice` shenanigans, you can simply access the previous element via its index. `foreach($result as $idx => $data)` - then you can simply use `$result[$idx-1]` to access the previous item. (That you don't want to do that in case $idx is 0, should go without saying.)

Comment: @DarkBee I edited my question in order to provide some example data and output. Please take a look. I hope it clarifies things! @Ferhat BAŞ and @CBroe Thx for your replies. I will look into both of your approaches. @CBroe I access the `$result` variable via the `$data` variable, which is starting at 0, yes! The problem I am having though, seems to lie within my nested foreach. Ill try to understand, apply and get back with what I got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As CBroe stated in the comments, you can just use the key/index in the foreach loop to create the sum

```php
<?php
    $data = [
        [
            'indexname0' => 'group-id',
            'indexname1' => 'name of 1st-item',
            'indexname2' => 'state of 1st-item',
            'indexname3' => 93.42,
            'indexname4' => 'unit of 1st-item',
        ],
        [
            'indexname0' => 'group-id',
            'indexname1' => 'name of 1st-item',
            'indexname2' => 'state of 1st-item',
            'indexname3' => 93.12,
            'indexname4' => 'unit of 1st-item',
        ],
        [
            'indexname0' => 'group-id',
            'indexname1' => 'name of 1st-item',
            'indexname2' => 'state of 1st-item',
            'indexname3' => 89.92,
            'indexname4' => 'unit of 1st-item',
        ],
        [
            'indexname0' => 'group-id',
            'indexname1' => 'name of 1st-item',
            'indexname2' => 'state of 1st-item',
            'indexname3' => 89.70,
            'indexname4' => 'unit of 1st-item',
        ],
    ];


    foreach($data as $index => $value) {
        if (!isset($data[$index+1])) continue;
        echo $data[$index+1]['indexname3'] - $data[$index]['indexname3'].'<br />';
    }
```

[demo](https://ideone.com/vHvOmo)

Comment: First of all thx for the code. This seems to be what I need. Unfortunately I am having trouble to adapt this to my szenario. While the `$data` variable you defined represents the final array, my `$data` variable is first defined in the foreach header (`$result as $data`). The `$result` variable, holds the result set from a prepared statement as a mysqli_result object, so I cannot access this like that. Therefore `$result as $index => $value` didnt work for me either. What am I missing? Thx ahead!

Comment: Just run the code after your first foreach? So after you've structured the SQL results into the new array

Comment: After struggling around with the code for a while, I finally made the right adjusments and got it to work, using `fetch_all(MYSQLI_NUM);` to create a numeric array out of my result set (`$result`) and using this in my existing foreach, but without nesting the above code in another foreach. Cheers!